# exchange accesstoken between auth0 and Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, auth0, google-signin

I’ve an app (app1) with Google social login implemented using Auth0. I can successfully login to this app with my google email and can see the token.

I’ve a REST api (api2) protected using Azure AD B2C with Google social login. I can call this API with a token returned by Azure AD B2C for my google email.

However the token returned by Auth0 and AzureAD B2C seems to be different, for the same google email.

How can I call the REST API in (API2) with auth token generated by app1 ? Based on my naive research I need to some token exchange through identity brokering. Any pointers or guidnace on how to would be greateful.

Thanks,
Mateen

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to federate both app1 and api2 with same IDP either B2C or Auth0. As the API is protected with B2C, it will not trust the token issued by Auth0.

However, you may try adding Auth0 as IDP to B2C so that rather than B2C directly connecting to Google IDP, it connects via Auth0. In that case, the token passed to app1 and B2C (to access API) will be same. I have not personally tested it out but you may give it a try and I would recommend to go with my first suggestion.